# How to keep a value in a PHP Session

Tags: php, session, session-variables

im save a base64 decode using session `$_SESSION['base64'] = base64_decode($_GET['url']);`, after im save it i want to destroy all session but i dont want to destroy  `$_SESSION['base64']`.

here my code

```
session_start();

if (isset($_GET['url'])) {
    $normal_link =  $_GET['idc'];
    $_SESSION['base64'] = base64_decode($_GET['url']);
    header('Location: save1.php?idc='.$normal_link);
}
/**/
if (isset($_SESSION['base64'])) {
    echo $_SESSION['base64'];
} else {
    echo "Base64 Session not Recorded";
}
session_unset();
session_destroy();
```

when im run my code it give me `Base64 Session not Recorded`. i want it give me url that i decode. is that posible to keep `$_SESSION['base64']` after destroy the session or maybe is there another way?

Comment: unless that redirects to itself, your session check won't happen

Answer (score 0):

You can use the default function to remove that `session_unregister('base64')`. More also in the [documentation](http://php.net/session_unregister).

but **important hint:** `session_unregister()` has been deprecated as of PHP 5.3.0 and **REMOVED** as of PHP 5.4.0.

So you should use use `unset`, like `unset($_SESSION['base64'])`.

Comment: He's asking to keep the value in the session, so I doubt he want to do an unset.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should check if you really want or need to destroy the session. If so, assuming that the  the value is not secret, you could redirect the browser to an url where you pass as parameter the base64 value, like you do when you redirect to save1.php, and then store it on the session again from there.